# Selenium+PHPunit: foreach element in collection

Tags: collections, selenium, foreach, phpunit, element

I am looking for a way to work with collections of elements in Selenium with PHPunit. Let's say I have the below code:

```
<div class="test">aaa</div>
<div class="test">bbb</div>
<div class="test">ccc</div>
```

I would like to be able to work on all the `<div>` elements inside an each loop, let's say by selecting the elements based on their class with `//div[@class='test']`

```
$divs = ...  // 
foreach ($divs as $div) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, if you want to work with some HTML data, a great solution is using the [**`DOMDocument`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class *-- which means being able to work with DOM methods --* via its [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method.

Loading your HTML with DOMDocument :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('HERE YOUR HTML STRING');
```

You can then instanciate a [**`DOMXpath`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) object :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Which will allow you to extract data from the HTML, using XPath Queries, with [**`DOMXPath::query()`**][4] :

```
$entries = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]'); // notice quotes
if ($entries->length > 0) {
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        // Work on the $entry -- which is a DOM node/element
    }
}
```

Comment: That's sorted for the PHP side, what I am missing now is the method to retrieve the page content from `$this` after I ran: $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
$this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
$this->open('http://www.example.com/');

Comment: I know there is a method to get the whole HTML of the page from Selenium ; I have used it a couple of years ago, but I don't remember its name :-( sorry -- going through the source-code, you might find it...

Answer (score 1):

The function to get the content of your entire page is :- getHtmlSource()
So your final function call to load HTML would be something like ..
$dom->loadHTML($this->getHtmlSource());